# Replace references of variables with their assignments done later in Python file

Tags: python, regex, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, visitor-pattern

I am converting a verilog file to python file using parsers and visitors. Problem is that verilog is a declarative language while python is an imperative one. So order of variable assignments doesn't matter in verilog but matters in python.

For e.g.

```
def F(XY_vars, util):
    i_0 = XY_vars[0, :]
    i_1 = XY_vars[1, :]
    i_2 = XY_vars[2, :]
    out = util.continuous_xor((w1),(i_2))
    w1 = util.continuous_xor((i_0),(i_1))
    return out
```

Observe that w1 is referenced before the assignment. If the value of w1 is directly passed to the function then the problem is solved. I know what all vars will be used and also their values.

Is there a way to perform this replacement of arguments with their values assigned anywhere in the file?

How can ast module be used here?

If I need to write python visitor for this, some help for how to do that would be appreciated.

For reference I'm adding the verilog file from which I generated the above python code.

```
// Test Sample 1: xor of 3 variables 

module formula ( i_0,i_1,i_2,out);
input i_0, i_1, i_2;
output out;
wire w1;
assign out = w1 ^ i_2;
assign w1 = i_0 ^ i_1;

endmodule
```

Thanks

Comment: This is probably not what you want to hear, but can you just run the code and wait for `variable referenced before assignment` errors and fix them one-by-one?

Comment: @quamrana I would have happily done that. But the problem is that files are not static but dynamically generated. As stated in the first para, these files are generated using visitor patterns to convert from verilog format to python format. And I need to do this for 100s of files. So manually removing errors is not an option. I want to automate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To robustly handle syntax analysis across many input samples, a solution at minimum has to account for function parameter names and scope. This solution works in two parts: first, using the `ast` module, the original code snippet is traversed and all assignments and expression objects "missing" an assignment binding are saved. Then, the tree is traversed once again, this time, missing expressions are replaced with their assignment target (if the latter exists):

```
import ast, itertools, collections as cl
class AssgnCheck:
   def __init__(self, scopes = None):
      self.scopes, self.missing = scopes or cl.defaultdict(lambda :cl.defaultdict(list)), []
   @classmethod
   def eq_ast(cls, a1, a2):
      #check that two `ast`s are the same
      if type(a1) != type(a2):
         return False
      if isinstance(a1, list):
         return all(cls.eq_ast(*i) for i in itertools.zip_longest(a1, a2))
      if not isinstance(a1, ast.AST):
         return a1 == a2
      return all(cls.eq_ast(getattr(a1, i, None), getattr(a2, i, None)) 
                 for i in set(a1._fields)|set(a2._fields) if i != 'ctx')
   def has_bindings(self, t_ast, s_path):
      #traverse the scope stack and yield `ast`s from t_ast that do not have a value assigned to them
      for _ast in t_ast:
         if not any(any(AssgnCheck.eq_ast(_ast, b) for _, b in self.scopes[sid]['names']) for sid in s_path[::-1]):
            yield _ast
   def traverse(self, _ast, s_path = [1]):
      #walk the ast object itself
      _t_ast = None
      if isinstance(_ast, ast.Assign): #if assignment statement, add ast object to current scope
         self.scopes[s_path[-1]]['names'].append((True, _ast.targets[0]))
         self.scopes[s_path[-1]]['bindings'].append((_ast.targets[0], _ast.value))
         _ast = _ast.value
      if isinstance(_ast, (ast.ClassDef, ast.FunctionDef, ast.AsyncFunctionDef)):
         s_path = [*s_path, (nid:=(1 if not self.scopes else max(self.scopes)+1))]
         if isinstance(_ast, (ast.FunctionDef, ast.AsyncFunctionDef)):
            self.scopes[nid]['names'].extend([(False, ast.Name(i.arg)) for i in _ast.args.args])
            _t_ast = [*_ast.args.defaults, *_ast.body]
      self.missing.extend(list(self.has_bindings(_t_ast if _t_ast is not None else [_ast], s_path))) #determine if current ast object instance has a value assigned to it
      if _t_ast is None:
         _ast.s_path = s_path
         for _b in _ast._fields:
            if isinstance((b:=getattr(_ast, _b)), list):
               for i in b:
                  self.traverse(i, s_path)
            elif isinstance(b, ast.AST):
               self.traverse(b, s_path)
      else:
          for _ast in _t_ast:
             _ast.s_path = s_path
             self.traverse(_ast, s_path)
```

---

Function to perform the substitutions:

```
import copy
def replace_vars(_ast, c_obj, sentinel):
   def ast_bindings(a, n, v, is_l = False):
      if not isinstance(v, ast.AST):
         return
      if v in c_obj.missing:
         c_obj.missing.remove(v)
         for sid in v.s_path[::-1]:
            if (k:=[y for x, y in c_obj.scopes[sid]['bindings'] if AssgnCheck.eq_ast(v, x)]):
               sentinel.f = True
               if not is_l:
                  setattr(a, n, copy.deepcopy(k[0]))
               else:
                  a[n] = copy.deepcopy(k[0])
               return
      replace_vars(v, c_obj, sentinel)
   if isinstance(_ast, ast.Assign):
      ast_bindings(_ast, 'value', _ast.value)
   else:
      for i in _ast._fields:
         if isinstance((k:=getattr(_ast, i)), list):
            for x, y in enumerate(k):
               ast_bindings(k, x, y, True)
         else:
            ast_bindings(_ast, i, k)
```

---

Putting it all together:

```
s = """
def F(XY_vars, util):
   i_0 = XY_vars[0, :]
   i_1 = XY_vars[1, :]
   i_2 = XY_vars[2, :]
   out = util.continuous_xor((w1),(i_2))
   w1 = util.continuous_xor((i_0),(i_1))
   return out
"""
class Sentinel:
   def __init__(self):
      self.f = False

def replace_preref(s):
   t = ast.parse(s)
   while True:
      a = AssgnCheck()
      a.traverse(t)
      s = Sentinel()
      replace_vars(t, a, s)
      if not s.f:
         break
   return ast.unparse(t)

print(replace_preref(s))
```

Output:

```
def F(XY_vars, util):
    i_0 = XY_vars[0, :]
    i_1 = XY_vars[1, :]
    i_2 = XY_vars[2, :]
    out = util.continuous_xor(util.continuous_xor(i_0, i_1), i_2)
    w1 = util.continuous_xor(i_0, i_1)
    return out
```

In the example above, the label `w_1` that was originally being passed as the first parameter to `util.continuous_xor` has been replaced with `w1`'s target assignment expression from below.

Second test sample:

```py
s = """
def F(XY_vars, util):    
    i_0 = XY_vars[0, :]    
    i_1 = XY_vars[1, :]    
    i_2 = XY_vars[2, :]    
    out = util.continuous_xor((w1),(i_2))    
    w2 = util.continuous_xor((i_0), (i_1))    
    w1 = util.continuous_xor((w2),(i_1))    
    return out
"""
print(replace_preref(s))
```

Output:

```
def F(XY_vars, util):
    i_0 = XY_vars[0, :]
    i_1 = XY_vars[1, :]
    i_2 = XY_vars[2, :]
    out = util.continuous_xor(util.continuous_xor(util.continuous_xor(i_0, i_1), i_1), i_2)
    w2 = util.continuous_xor(i_0, i_1)
    w1 = util.continuous_xor(w2, i_1)
    return out
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It works perfectly for the example given in the question but fails for following: 

**`def F(XY_vars, util):
   i_0 = XY_vars[0, :]
   i_1 = XY_vars[1, :]
   i_2 = XY_vars[2, :]
   out = util.continuous_xor((w1),(i_2))
   w2 = util.continuous_xor((i_0), (i_1))
   w1 = util.continuous_xor((w2),(i_1))
   return out`**
For such a code requires your prescribed solution to be run recursively till all replacements are done. Is there a way to recursively replace every "reference before assignment"?

Comment: @RaviRaja Glad to help!